# How to play animation and remove all in continuous order using gestureDetector onPanUpdate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

This is the statefulWidget where I have included the `GestureDetector` and `onPanUpdate` callback. This means if the pointer is in contact with the screen we can do something right. Here I am adding a generateBox if the  user is dragging on the screen. In generateBox() method I have included a simple animation which rotate according to the value of pi and after 500 milliseconds as soon as the animation complete [onEnd](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder/TweenAnimationBuilder.html) callback is invoked where I am removing the array List from index 0(zero) which is from first element of the array list.

This is the [animation](https://giphy.com/gifs/animation-ios-duration-YYb0HJae45U4MCq2kn/fullscreen) I want to solve using Flutter.

I tried the same above [animation with Flutter](https://giphy.com/gifs/animation-ios-notworking-nKx9htr9saa8F9heoc/fullscreen) but it did not work as expected.

When we start dragging onPanUpdate callback is generating all the container and animating also but it is not removing all the container on the screen in continuous order as I mentioned to remove them when Animation end in onEnd callback of TweenAnimationBuilder. As I want in the animation gif above.

I know a good Flutterist and GDE in Dart and Flutter can solve this very well.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var myWidgetList = <Widget>[];
  var xPosition = 0.0;
  var yPosition = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        setState(() {
          xPosition = details.localPosition.dx;
          yPosition = details.localPosition.dy;

          myWidgetList.add(generateBox());
        });
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: myWidgetList.toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // To Generate Animated Box for 500 milliseconds.

  Widget generateBox() {
    return Positioned(
      left: xPosition,
      top: yPosition,
      child: TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        builder: (_, double angle, __) {
          return Transform.rotate(
            angle: angle,
            child: Container(
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3,
                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                ),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        onEnd: () {
          myWidgetList.remove(myWidgetList[0]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```